# React: create-react-app fails with error "Cannot find module 'lodash'"

Tags: reactjs, lodash, create-react-app

I'm learning React for the first time, and I'm having a great deal of trouble even getting started with a demo app. When I run `npx create-react-app` I get the following error:

[image]

This is on Windows 10, npm/npx version 6.4.1. I tried `npm install` and installing lodash using `npm i -g lodash`, which tells me lodash 4.17.11 is installed. But the `create-react-app` command is still generating the exact same error message.

This seems very bizarre. I've looked around online and cannot find any other references to this error as it relates to the `create-react-app` command, and the solutions on other answers (`npm install`/`npm i -s lodash`) are not working (-s requires that an app folder be created in advance of using `create-react-app`, but `create-react-app` requires that the app folder be completely empty).

How do I approach resolving this problem so that I can get started with building my first react app and learning the framework?

**Update - package.json**

The package.json is being deleted by the command, but if I open it in notepad++, the last version before the installer crashes seems to contain contain the following minimal information.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

The only file left over after the installation seems to be a package-lock.json, which is very lengthy 0.6mb. I can post it somewhere if needed.

Comment: Can you post your package.json file here?

Comment: @ShubhamJain It gets deleted by the installer, but I captured the text it contained just as the installer crashed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I continued searching for similar problems that others have had, and someone suggested:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

so I did that, then I did another:

```
npm i
```

and ...

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

then the create-react-app command worked!!

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: you could also use the *Yarn* way 

`yarn create react-app my-app` 

This will fix your NPX problem, it did for me, rather than install the `create-react-app` again

Answer (score 1):

did you try installing create-react-app? `npm install -g create-react-app` and then run `create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Yes the create-react-app is installed and runs, but it is crashing.