# create react app error Cannot find module './node'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I tried to run `create-react-app myapp` and everytime it throws an error

I tried to clean the cache by `npm cache clean --force`

but it didn't fix the problem

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Design\react\myapp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:8:11)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

Aborting installation.
node  has failed.
```

My node version
v10.17.0

My npm version
6.11.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632987/1006272 have you tried this

Comment: @berniefitz yes i tried it didnt work. create-react-app deletes folder after it stops with error so `npm i` is useless

Comment: you try `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install` ?

Comment: @Chev after the error it deletes the folder. where should i run these commands

Comment: run those from the root of your project where you `package.json` is installed and your `node_modules` folder was. then try `npm install` again

Comment: @Chev that's the point i tried to create project . but after the error "create-react-app" deletes the folder;

Answer (score 2):

I was presenting the same problem, until I realized that I had an instance of create-react-app installed globally, apparently this generates a kind of conflict, I solved it as follows:

- Check the npm folder in the following path: C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm

I noticed that in this npm folder I had executable files of create-react-app. So I deleted all the npm folder and also uninstall node and reinstalled it and that solved my problem. I hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the create-react-app is not fully deleted from global packages, so to delete it completely `goto 'C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm'` and **delete** the
**create-react-app.cmd** file

[Picture showing which file to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PukkI.png)

Answer (score 1):

To show a list of globally installed packages:

```
npm -g list
```

To install create-react-app globally:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

I will use:

```
npx create-react-app [project-name]
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you just install react app latest on your terminal dude. npx-create-app@latest .  (.) react is installed in an existing folder. hoppely this my answer help to solve your problem