# I have a problem trying to create a react application - Error: Cannot find module './gitignore'

Tags: reactjs, git

I am a windows user, I have git, node and yarn installed. Which are required to create my React application and I get an error which aborts the installation. Can you tell me how to solve it, because I have installed and uninstalled node and git which one of the two I think is causing problems or missing folders?

```
PS C:\React> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\React\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 13 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.9.4
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1
Done in 34.13s.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './gitignore'
Require stack:
- C:\React\my-app\node_modules\globby\index.js
- C:\React\my-app\node_modules\react-dev-utils\globby.js
- C:\React\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js
- C:\React\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js
- C:\React\my-app\[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\React\my-app\node_modules\globby\index.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\React\\my-app\\node_modules\\globby\\index.js',
    'C:\\React\\my-app\\node_modules\\react-dev-utils\\globby.js',
    'C:\\React\\my-app\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\utils\\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js',
    'C:\\React\\my-app\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\init.js',
    'C:\\React\\my-app\\[eval]'
  ]
}

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting my-app/ from C:\React
Done.
PS C:\React>
```

Comment: Have you installed create-react-app globaly ?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're not trying to import `gitignore` somewhere in your project by accident. Do a search for it across all of your code files.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the suggestions from this post: [React: create-react-app fails with error "Cannot find module 'lodash'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632233/react-create-react-app-fails-with-error-cannot-find-module-lodash).

That is, run:

```
npm cache clean --force 
npm i 
npm i -g create-react-app
```

And then try this command again:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

clear yarn cache
type this command in your terminal:

```
yarn cache clean
```