# React: create-react-app fails with error "Cannot find module 'libnpx'

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, npm

OS-ubuntu

IDE-VS-Code

`npx create-react-app` was working fine,I wanted to work on a personal project when i run in to a suggestion that `Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.` I tried updating node using the following commands `sudo npm cache clean -f` and then `sudo npm install -g n` then i ran  `sudo n stable` the following was installed   installed : v16.13.1 (with npm 8.1.2).When i tried running `npx create-react-app` I got the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'libnpx'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/bin/npx-cli.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/share/npm/bin/npx-cli.js' ]
}
```

What i tried after getting the error,
The solution below;
[React: create-react-app fails with error "Cannot find module 'lodash'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632233/react-create-react-app-fails-with-error-cannot-find-module-lodash)

How do I approach resolving this problem so that I can get started with my personal project and learning the framework?

Answer (score 7):

Restart your terminal after updating node version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Restarted vs-code and it started working fine.Hope this helps someone facing the same error